# I have issue in creating admin user for Voyager Admin panel package in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, voyager

after voyage package installation with this command :

```
php artisan voyager:install
```

I needed to create admin user with this command :

```
php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com --create
```

and then entering the name and the password

The problem is after entering the username and the password it's returning this error

> General error: 1364 Field 'employee_name' doesn't have a default value
>   (SQL: insert into `employee` (`email`) values (admin@admin.com))

and I have already a database but with different naming convention for example: 
the users table I call it employee and the name field called employee_name

My question is , is there any way to map the expected fields in voyager with my actual fields in my database because I can't change them ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you altered the normal structure of the User model and will likely run into similar issues with other packages that try to add users, you could create a boot() method in the user model to set this->employee_name to this->name and then unset this->name so that when records from other packages try to use the name attribute you correct it to the employee_name attribute.

This is off the top of my head based on memory so it may involve a bit more 'logic' but I think if you look into the boot method you will see that you can do this type of thing. I have used it to autofill columns with dynamically based values.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

When you're executing this command, Voyager [creates a new user](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.0/src/Commands/AdminCommand.php#L128) for you using the mass assignment feature.

So, add `$fillable` to the `User` model:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
```

Comment: first thanks for your answer .. but I think there is Misunderstanding .. the voyager package is creating new user and it expects a column called name .. that is not exists in my table .. the name column called employee_name in my table .. So it doesn't insert the row with employee_name column .. and the employee_name column doesn't have a default value so it throws that error

Comment: here is what I did in my model as you suggested

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password','employee_name'
    ];

Comment: @AliReda why don't you rename `employee_name` to `name`?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'employee_name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `employee` (`email`, `password`) values (admin@admin.com, hashedPassword))

Comment: because this I have to change that in many sql statements in a lot of controllers .. and there is an other apps that works with this database so I can't change the table name or it's columns

Comment: @AliReda in this case, you'll need to manually add the data with seeder or something because `name` is hardcoded in the command.

Comment: I think this is a logical and possible solution .. Thank you for your Time

Answer (score 0):

> General error: 1364 Field 'employee_name' doesn't have a default value

You can set default value to null in your database this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to refer any attempt to add data to 'name' column to 'employee_name'.

For your case:

App\User.php

```
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['employee_name'] = $value;
}
```